# Data flattening into view model

Tags: c#

I want to flattening this data into a new model that is a list of view models base off of the numbers of SubmissionRequestFiles. So because there is two SubmissionRequestFiles there should be two SubmissionRequestViewModel

```
        SubmissionRequestViewModel vm = new SubmissionRequestViewModel();
        vm.SubmissionId = sr.SubmissionId;
    
        foreach (var file in sr.SubmissionRequestFiles)
        {
          vm.SubmissionRequestFilesName = file.SubmissionRequestFilesName;
        }
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/mKDEnI

Comment: Have you tried `srfsList.Select(x => new SubmissionRequestViewModel() { ... })` ?

Comment: yes but that will not add the SubmissionId

Comment: I associate the term 'flattening' with some kind of hierarchical data structure, like a tree, that is transformed into a linear structure. If you already have a regular plain linear collection I would use a term like 'transform', or 'map'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/):

```cs
List<SubmissionRequestViewModel> vms = sr.SubmissionRequestFiles
    .Select(f => new SubmissionRequestViewModel
    {
        SubmissionId = sr.SubmissionId,
        SubmissionRequestFilesName = f.SubmissionRequestFilesName
    })
    .ToList();
```

now `vms` will have an entry per file.